# MYSQL order by date with DATE_FORMAT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column (`startdate`) of type DATE.

I'm using DATE_FORMAT to get "Month XX, XXXX" results from the query.

But when I ORDER BY the dates get sorted alphabetically... how do I order the date chronologically?

Can I format the startdate column differently when I call it in the ORDER BY so it sorts chronologically?

Here's the query...

```
SELECT location, course, DATE_FORMAT( startdate, '%M %D, %Y' ) AS startdate 
    FROM `courses` c 
    LEFT JOIN `locdate` l ON c.id = l.id 
    ORDER BY startdate ASC 
    LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: As @Marc answered , `ORDER BY l.startdate ASC` is fine but change `DATE_FORMAT(l.startdate, '%M %D, %Y' ) AS startdate` to `DATE_FORMAT(l.startdate, '%M %D, %Y' ) AS startdate_MDY` and where you use `startdate` in your script , use `startdate_MDY` instead .

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using aliases.  I have to guess where the columns come from, but here is an attempt:

```
SELECT l.location, c.course, DATE_FORMAT(l.startdate, '%M %D, %Y' ) AS startdate 
FROM `courses` c 
LEFT JOIN `locdate` l ON c.id = l.id 
ORDER BY l.startdate ASC 
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

By using the table alias, it knows to use the version from the table column.

Answer (score 0):

Don't sort by your formatted string version. it's not in a format that allows for such ordering, because it's not in most-significant-components-first ordering. Sort by the ACTUAL date field, which will naturally sort in proper order.

If your date was in `yyyy mm dd` format, then it'd naturally sort as a string.

```
SELECT ...   DATE_FORMAT(...) AS formatted    ... ORDER BY `startdate` ASC
                                 ^^^^^^^^--different alias   ^^^^^^---actual field
```

Answer (score 0):

I have only just came across this problem, but here is my solution.
Have your normal formatted date, then add an extra column

```
$query = "SELECT `StartDate` as datesort,DATE_FORMAT(`StartDate`,'%d %M %Y') as Date, FROM `courses`";
```

I am taking `StartDate` and aliasing it to datesort. Then I use datesort to do the sorting. This way I can keep StartDate formatted and I use datesort to do the sorting.

This is an annoying problem, but my method sorts it (ignore the pun).